# HTML drop down link open in new tab

Tags: html, dropdown

i have this DOWNLOAD button

```
<a href="" id="user-name" class="link" id="posi">Download</a>
```

and the drop down associated with this

```
 <div class="user-name-drop-down drop-down">
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Android</a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com">Apple</a>

    </div>
```

when clicked on android or apple, it opens the link on the same tab, i want it to open in a new tab instead. i looked up about `window.open` but still unclear as to how to use that. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add target="_blank" property to the anchor element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using attribute of `<a>` i.e `target`

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Android</a>
        <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Apple</a>
```

you can refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) link.

Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="user-name-drop-down drop-down">
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Android</a>
    <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Apple</a>

</div>
```

use this code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="user-name-drop-down drop-down">
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">Android</a>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">Apple</a>

</div>
```

Try this

Answer (score 1):

Use target = _blank as

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">Android</a>
<a target="_blank" href="https://www.google.com">Apple</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can use `target="_blank"` in your `<a href="" ></a>` tag.

```
<div class="user-name-drop-down drop-down">
   <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Android</a>
   <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">Apple</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use _blank  which opens the linked document in a new window or tab.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp